# Yii2 How to handle XML response from an api callback

Tags: xml, yii2

I am expecting an xml response from a callback URL. The callback is set to something like.

> http:://example.com/index/controllerExample/ActionResponseView

Sample XML from callback URL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="tns:ns">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:ResultMsg>
  <PHONE_NUMBER ns1:type="xsd:string">XXXXXXXXXX</PHONE_NUMBER>
  </ns1:ResultMsg>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Using yii2 standards where do i initialise the DOMDocument. Should it go in the controllerExample or directly in the ActionResponseView ?

```
$xmlFromServer = file_get_contents('php://input');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlFromServer);

$res = $doc->getElementsByTagName("PHONE_NUMBER");
$PHONE_NUMBER = $res->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: In `ActionResponseView`. If you use wsdl for soap service - try wsdl2php, it will handle SOAP for you.

Comment: @ineersa the callback is done by the api....at their own time after ending the soap request with the callback url to be use to update fields. Thanks i was a little skeptical about having the xml in the view.  I thought there was a better way of handling it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can just define custom response format and in controller write simple `return ['PHONE_NUMBER' => 'XXXXXXXXXX'];`.

In configuration write:

```
'components' => [
    'response' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Response', //It may be your custom response
        'format' => 'MyApi',
        'formatters' => [
            'MyApi' => 'app\api\MyApiFormatter'
        ]
    ],
];
```

Your formatter should extends `XmlResponseFormatter` and change `format` method.

In this way in controller you care only for correct data, in Formatter you care only for response format.

Comment: I like your idea but from my understanding i think this implementation is for creating an xml so that the view been rendered will render a valid xml/json. Kindly clarify cause for me i want to consume an xml by executing an action . Also can you expound on the structure of the controller in terms of how i can consume the received xml. Thanks